# Add Header Row To Array Of Filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an array of filters that builds three columns

={
FILTER(HSGrps1!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps1!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
FILTER(HSGrps2!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps2!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2,0));
FILTER(HSGrps3!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps3!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
}

item    item
item    item
item    item
item    item

**How could I add a header row of plain text inside that array?**

={
FILTER(HSGrps1!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps1!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
FILTER(HSGrps2!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps2!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2,0));
**"Header Row Here"**
FILTER(HSGrps3!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps3!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
}

e.g.
item    item
item    item
item    item
item    item
**Header Row Here**
item    item
item    item

Comment: I tried that @Marios, it does not work - In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom text:

```
={
FILTER(HSGrps1!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps1!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
FILTER(HSGrps2!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps2!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2,0));
{"Header1","Header2"};
FILTER(HSGrps3!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps3!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
}
```

For text based on a range:

```
={
FILTER(HSGrps1!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps1!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
FILTER(HSGrps2!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps2!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2,0));
{A1:B1};
FILTER(HSGrps3!$A$2:$C,MATCH(HSGrps3!$C$2:$C,Formulas!$F$2:$F,0));
}
```

where A1 contains `Header1` and B1 contains `Header2` for example.

Comment: Both methods give me this error: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: are you sure the result of the filter formulas are two columns? please provide a copy of your sheet. @Mathias

Comment: You are most observant and I cannot count. That works thank you!